# The python request was detected by server-side anti-crawlers

Tags: python, web-crawler

When I was crawling a website, my python request was detected by the server and did not return the correct data, but my python request went through the Charles local proxy and I was able to get the data. How does the server check for requests using python? I've replaced the user-agent and other request headers.

I tried using requests and aiohttp, and both were detected, but the correct data was returned through the charles proxy.

Copying a browser request as a bash curl request will not succeed either, but copying a powershell request will get the correct data

Comment: One way to detect it is order of HTTP request headers. Probably there are dozens of other ways, including TLS byte stream profiling.

Comment: did you aadd the browser identity to the request ?